# The commands \wd, \tp and \ht in TikZ/PGF

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, dimensions

What does these commands, `\wd`, `\tp` and `\ht` stand for? I assumed that they are from TikZ and PGF, because I haven't seen them elsewhere.

I think the `\wd` stands for "width" and the `\ht` stands for "height", and they somehow obtain the width and the height of the shape that comes after.

I would like to know if I am right about that. Then I would like to know what `\tp` stands for, and finally I want to ask, if there is any other such commands out there.

I looked for them in the manual to no avail, then also on Google, but the phrase is just too short, probably.

Comment: I think you mean `\wd`, `\ht` and `\dp` (not `\tp`) which are TeX primitives for getting the width, height and depth of a box. See chapter 5 "Boxes" in "TeX by Topic" by Victor Eijkhout for some suitably gory details. You can get it [here](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/texbytopic?lang=en).

Comment: @MarkWibrow An answer?

Comment: @egreg Should be...

Comment: Updated version (revision 1.5, 2019) of Eijkhout's *TeX by Topic*: https://web.corral.tacc.utexas.edu/CompEdu/pdf/TeX/TeXbyTopic.pdf

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`\wd`, `\ht` and `\dp` (not `\tp`) are TeX primitives for getting the width, height and depth of a box (respectively).

So, for example,

```
\newbox\mybox
\setbox\mybox=\hbox{\vrule width10pt height20pt depth 30pt}
\typeout{width=\the\wd\mybox, height=\the\ht\mybox, depth=\the\dp\mybox}
```

will produce

```
width=10.0pt, height=20.0pt, depth=30.0pt
```

Somewhere in the log-file.

More details on boxes can be found in chapter 5 ("Boxes") from [TeX by Topic](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/texbytopic?lang=en) by Victor Eijkhout.

Comment: You may provide a "better" link: http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/plain/texbytopic/TeXbyTopic.pdf#page64